# Regex with grep does not give output with 0

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am using grep to do regex in a csv file which contains lines like this:

```
29/10/2020,29/10/2020,08017360,Open,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I am trying to match all the ones starting by "08"(third column). However it doesn't output anything. If I try it with any other number other than 0, it gives me the results accordingly. My regex is as follows:

```
grep "^[^,]\+,[^,]\+10\+[^,]\+,08" xxx.csv
```

To me it seems that is treating zero as a different character than a number.

Can you tell me why is this behaviour and the best way to sort it using grep?

Thank you

Comment: grep is not the right tool for parsing CSV. Consider using special tools or programming languages that support CSV parsing.

Comment: Your `grep` works - see [proof](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v9hWychS39BA38jAyEAHiWlgYWBobmxmoONfkJqnY4AJlbhSkzPyFZRUipUUahTSi1ILFJTiouN0YmO0dSCUoUGMNlTAwELp/38A).

Comment: Thank you @RyszardCzech for the proof. Yes I checked it too and it works. Now I wonder why it does not work on my Ubuntu machine. Perhaps a different version of Grep is causing this behaviour? Cheers.

Comment: I tested on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and it worked, too.

Comment: @RyszardCzech : While I could verify that it **does** match, I don't understand why it should match. The pattern contains spurious `\+`  embedded, which in case of `grep` mean an unnecessary escape of  the `+` (unnecessary, because lacking the -E option, the `+` has no special meaning anyway). Hence it should match a literal `+` in the subject string, which is not present. I would have expected a no-match.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk and a regex. Output every line in which third column starts with `08`:

```
awk -F ',' '$3 ~ /^08/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

It is safer to use a CSV parser. If you are certain that you do not have CSV with comma in a cell like `aaa,"bbb,bbb",ccc`, and no newlines in cells you can use a simple grep.

Here is your example:

```
$ echo '29/10/2020,29/10/2020,08017360,Open,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0' | egrep '^([^,]*,){2}08'
29/10/2020,29/10/2020,08017360,Open,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
$
$ echo '29/10/2020,29/10/2020,08017360,Open,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0' | egrep '^([^,]*,){2}09'
$
```

Explanation:

- use egrep for better regex support
- `([^,]*,)` captures a cell, including trailing comma
- `{2}` - repeats the preceding captured text twice, e.g. scans over two cells including commas
- `08` - expect `08` after that